# Call to other class does not get executed

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm having (I assume) a generic problem with a call to another class.

The call to the other CCLayer:

```
MyLayer *myLayer = [MyLayer node];
[myLayer methodName];
```

that's the method implementation in 'myLayer':

```
-(void) methodName
{
    NSLog(@"methodName gets called"); // works
    [mySprite runAction:[CCBlink actionWithDuration:1.0 blinks:5]]; // works not
}
```

The action on 'mySprite' does work (when called from within that class), but there seems to be an
issue with 'rights' or 'hierarchy' related to this layer class which prevents the execution of the command
from outside.

Since I'm a beginner in Objective-C it's kind of a 'mystery' to me.
I appreciate any help or insight on this, it would be helpful to many newbies.

Thanks!

btw:

```
@interface

CCSprite *mySprite;

@property (nonatomic,retain) CCSprite *mySprite;

@implementation

@synthesize mySprite;


mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"mySprite.png"];
```

Comment: Have you checked that `mySprite` is not `nil`?

Comment: yes, as i mentioned from within it is working

Comment: When you say it's not working, do you mean that it crashes? Note that in the last line of code you are not retaining the value returned by `spriteWithSpriteFrameName:` since you are **not** using the property, you are accessing the backing ivar directly.

Comment: with not working i mean the 'action' on my sprite is NOT executed - the NSLog message though is, in other words - the call from another class gets through - but the 'action' is not working - which does not mean it crashes - the 'action' does not work on the sprite. how about you give me an example of how it should look like - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

is the function declared in your @interface so that it can be called from outside the class?

```
@interface

CCSprite *mySprite;

@property (nonatomic,retain) CCSprite *mySprite;

-(void)methodName;
```

Comment: how else - like i wrote is the NSLog being executed - if I would not have declared that function in the interface? - as you can see it's not a class method - it's an instance method - but thanks! look at my 2nd comment from above.

Comment: can you show us more code then to try figure out what your doing wrong

Comment: also are u adding the layer to the current scene or layer? that would allow the function to still be called but the sprite is not added so no action would be visible [self addchild:myLayer]; for example

Comment: glogic: the layer i'm making the call to is added to my game-scene with [scene addchild:myLayerA], and the layer i'm making the call from is added to my game-scene with [self addchild:myLayerB] in game-scene init - does that help?

Comment: and do u have a pointer in myLayerB to the sprite that is in myLayerA? How does myLayerB know that the sprite exists in myLayerA? would be better if you link the code for the 2 layers above and the gamescene init code